# Powerbuilder 12.5 Database profile Setup

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm new to powerbuilder 12.5. When I try to set-up database profile, data source column width is small enough to fit to our database server name. We had this issue in powerbuilder 10.0. But after installing patches PB 10.2, we can enter the full server name. Currently, I replaced the server name with ip_address and port name for connecting to db temporarily.

Also when I open property of work space to configure source control, powerbuilder keep crashing.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Sukumar

Comment: For the source control problem, you may need to add [JavaVM] CreateJavaVM=0 to your PB.ini. http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-pb/pbr1021e/pbentrb1021/@Generic__BookTextView/576;hf=0

Answer (score 0):

you could solve the long server name, that you export the Database profile (Tools\Database Profile). It makes an ini file (text file) like this:

```
[DBMS_PROFILES]

Profiles=TestProfile


[Profile QS]
DBMS=OLE DB
Database=
UserId=
DatabasePassword=
LogId=TestUser
LogPassword=
ServerName=
DBParm=PROVIDER='SQLOLEDB',DATASOURCE='MyVeryLongServerName\MyVeryLongInstanceName_MayTheForceBeWithYou_ALWAYS',PROVIDERSTRING='database=StarWarsDB'
Lock=
Prompt=FALSE
AutoCommit=FALSE
NewLogic=EAS
```

You should see your Database IP address after the DATASOURCE. Simply edit this file (change the IP for your db name). After this you can Import the database profile. I hope it helps :)

Br
Gábor

Comment: Thanks for your Help. Even after export and import profiles, I can't see server names and port numbers in full. However, I can able to connect to database.